# What is the meaning of this notation, D lag t?

Tags: probability, market-microstructure

I'm reading the book Financial Markets Under the Microscope to study market microstructure. There is a notation that I could not understand. What is the meaning of D here? It is not used in the text before and after that point. So I could not give meaning. Is it an operator?

Thanks

[image: Financial Markets Under the Microscope]

Comment: Given the variogram grows linearly in time $\tau$, it might be a constant, but it would a bit of misleading notation. As you say it looks like an operator, however $\tau$ is merely a time lag so an operator should not apply.

Comment: In my humble option D is a constant which multiplies the variable $\tau$

Comment: Might be motivated by the fact that D is commonly used to represent the diffusion coefficient as in the diffusion/ heat equation